# is there a way in argocd that i can take values.yaml dymically in application sets?

Tags: devops, argocd

is there a way in argocd that i can take values.yaml dymically on namespace in application sets for example

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: xxxx-application-set
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
  - list:
      elements:
      - namespace: namespace1
      - namespace: namespace2
      - namespace: namespace3
  template:      
    metadata:
      name: '{{namespace}}-test'
    spec:
      project: default


      source:
        repoURL: XXXX.git
        targetRevision: HEAD
        path: xxxx
        helm:
        valueFiles:
          - 'values-{{namespace}}'.yaml
```

cusomtize the values for each namespace as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good actually what you did there but I would try with

```
valueFiles:
  - "values-{{namespace}}.yaml"
```

I guess this should work.

Or you can try this:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: xxxx-application-set
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
  - list:
      elements:
      - namespace: namespace1
        valuesfile: namespace1_values.yaml
      - namespace: namespace2
        valuesfile: namespace2_values.yaml
      - namespace: namespace3
        valuesfile: namespace3_values.yaml
  template:      
    metadata:
      name: '{{namespace}}-test'
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: XXXX.git
        targetRevision: HEAD
        path: xxxx
        helm:
        valueFiles:
          - $valuesfile #or "{{valuesfile}}
```

As you can see in this page you can use build environment variables for the Helm values file path.

[Helm Docu](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/helm/#values-files:%7E:text=It%27s%20also%20possible%20to%20use%20build%20environment%20variables%20for%20the%20Helm%20values%20file%20path%3A)